# Airflow not Launching Locally: "No viable dags retrieved" Error

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using Apache Airflow 2.1.4
I have a DAG definition in a file named client.py, located in the dags directory.
My configuration file dag_configs.json is located in the config directory within the project structure.
I've confirmed that my dags_folder configuration in airflow.cfg is set to the correct directory.
I've verified that my DAG definition (client.py) is correctly structured, and I've followed best practices.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
import json
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import os

config_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class TaskID:
    RunClientQuery = "run_client_query"
    CreateTempTable = "create_temp_table"
    GetTransferConfigJson = "get_transfer_config_json"
    CreateTransfer = "create_transfer"
    StartTransfer = "start_transfer"
    ExtractData = "extract_data"
    ExportToClient = "export_to_client"


DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    "owner": "delivery-squad",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "wait_for_downstream": False,
    "email": [""],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 2,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2),
    "catchup": True,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

def create_dag(dag_id, schedule_interval, query_directory):
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=f"{dag_id}_client_delivery",
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        catchup=False,
    )

    run_client_query = DummyOperator(
        task_id=TaskID.RunClientQuery,
        dag=dag
    )
    create_temp_data = DummyOperator(
        task_id=TaskID.CreateTempTable,
        dag=dag
    )
    transfer_data =  DummyOperator(
        task_id=TaskID.StartTransfer,
        dag=dag)
    extract_data = DummyOperator(
        task_id=TaskID.ExtractData,
        dag=dag
    )
    export_to_client = DummyOperator(
        task_id=TaskID.ExportToClient,
        dag=dag
    )

    run_client_query >> create_temp_data >> transfer_data >> extract_data >> export_to_client

    return dag

config_file_path = os.path.join(config_dir, '../config/dag_configs.json')

with open(config_file_path) as f:
    config_data = json.load(f)

query_directory = "queries"  # Replace this with the actual path

for config in config_data:
    dag_id = config["dag_id"]
    schedule_interval = config["schedule_interval"]
    query_directory_placeholder = config["query_directory"]

    query_directory_actual = query_directory_placeholder.replace("{{QUERY_DIRECTORY}}", query_directory)

    globals()[dag_id] = create_dag(dag_id, schedule_interval, query_directory_actual)
```

Error message

```
[2023-08-08 10:40:12,582] {processor.py:162} INFO - Started process (PID=27475) to work on ...
[2023-08-08 10:40:12,582] {processor.py:613} INFO - Processing file ... client_delivery_dag.py for tasks to queue
[2023-08-08 10:40:12,583] {dagbag.py:496} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from ... client_delivery_dag.py
[2023-08-08 10:40:12,585] {processor.py:625} WARNING - No viable dags retrieved from ... client_delivery_dag.py
```

Expected Outcome:
I expect Airflow to successfully retrieve and execute my DAGs. I've double-checked the configuration, syntax, and directory structure, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. I suspect there might be something I'm missing or misunderstanding.

My configuration file dag_configs.json is located in the config directory within the project structure.
I've confirmed that my dags_folder configuration in airflow.cfg is set to the correct directory.
I've verified that my DAG definition (client.py) is correctly structured, and I've followed best practices.
i use first

```
airflow db init
```

then

```
airflow webserver --port 8080
```

But it's unable to launch in local

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66994558/7004653) might help. Also, 2.1.4 is like 2 years old. I strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version of Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Right now your operators aren't being associated with the dag being created. Using with dag with automatically catch any operators and assigned them to the DAG:

```
def create_dag(dag_id, schedule_interval, query_directory):
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id=f"{dag_id}_client_delivery",
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        catchup=False,
    )

    with dag:
        run_client_query = DummyOperator(
            task_id=TaskID.RunClientQuery,
            dag=dag
        )
        create_temp_data = DummyOperator(
            task_id=TaskID.CreateTempTable,
            dag=dag
        )
        transfer_data =  DummyOperator(
            task_id=TaskID.StartTransfer,
            dag=dag)
        extract_data = DummyOperator(
            task_id=TaskID.ExtractData,
            dag=dag
        )
        export_to_client = DummyOperator(
            task_id=TaskID.ExportToClient,
            dag=dag
        )

        run_client_query >> create_temp_data >> transfer_data >> extract_data >> export_to_client

    return dag
```